# Remove vertical spacing in the table between rows

Tags: tables

[image]

Sorry for the blurred image but it should be clear that there is a vertical space between the first and second rows. I want to remove it but do not know the cause. Pasted is the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{rawfonts}

%\usepackage{times,amsmath,epsfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakcites}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xr}
%\externaldocument{supp}

% \doublespacing

%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% correct bad hyphenation here


\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Random Table}
\label{tab:main} 
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|M{0.25\linewidth} M{0.1\linewidth} M{0.3\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth} M{0.15\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth} M{0.15\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth} M{0.15\linewidth}|}
\hline

Dataset & ${n_{a}}$ & {Method} & s2 (\%) & s3 & s4 (\%) &
s5 & s6 & s7 & s8 & {\emph{something}}  \\
\hline

\multirow[c]{6}{*}{jgifosjgs}

& \multirow[c]{3}{*}{jgiosjgs} & gjiosfgjfsi & 5 & 10 & 52 & 3.27 & -086 & 0.03 & 3.9 & 2.01   \\ 
&& ngfiosjgofs & 37 & 3.1 & 73 & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5 & 2.58  \\
&& jgiofsjgfs & 2.6 & 65.4 & 57 & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10 & 9 & 82 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (Why are you using `6` with the first `\multirow`? There are only three rows remaining.) Anyway, remove the empty lines in your `tabular`.

Comment: And don't resizebox a table.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't reject trying tabularray, then tabularray is a good choice.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Random Table}
\label{tab:main}
\centering
\small
\begin{tblr}
{
rows         = {halign=c},
columns      = {valign=m,co=-1},
columns      = {colsep=0pt},
cell{2}{1,2} = {r=3}{},
hline{1,Z}   = {wd=.08em},
hline{2}     = {wd=.05em},
cell{1}{Z}   = {cmd=\emph},
}
Dataset   & $n_{a}$  & Method      & s2 (\%) & s3   & s4 (\%) & s5   & s6   & s7    & s8  & something \\
jgifosjgs & jgiosjgs & gjiosfgjfsi & 5       & 10   & 52      & 3.27 & -086 & 0.03  & 3.9 & 2.01      \\
          &          & ngfiosjgofs & 37      & 3.1  & 73      & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5   & 2.58      \\
          &          & jgiofsjgfs  & 2.6     & 65.4 & 57      & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10    & 9   & 82        \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix the arguments of `\multirow`.

No need for the `\resizebox` sledgehammer -- switching from fixed-width columns to `c` columns, using `\small`, and switching to a `tabular*` environment is all it takes to make the table fit within the width of the text block.

I've annotated your preamble code. Do please try to simplify and steamline your coding practices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{rawfonts}

%\usepackage{times,amsmath,epsfig}
%%%\usepackage{epsfig} % is loaded automatically by graphicx
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx} % don't load packages more than once
\usepackage{xurl} % 'xurl' is more powerful than 'url' package
%%%\usepackage{subfigure} % is deprecated, use 'subcaption' instead; see also below
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn} % are you sure you need this package?
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
%%%\usepackage{amssymb} % don't load packages more than once
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}
%%%\usepackage{breakcites} % obsolete

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[justification=centering,
            skip=0.333\baselineskip
           ]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <-- new 
\usepackage{float}

%%%\usepackage{graphics} % is loaded automatically by graphicx

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xr}
%\externaldocument{supp}

% \doublespacing

%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% correct bad hyphenation here

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h!]
\small % 10% linear reduction of font size
\captionsetup{font=small}
\caption{Random Table}
\label{tab:main} 
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{11}{c}}
\hline

Dataset & $n_{a}$ & Method & s2 (\%) & s3 & s4 (\%) &
s5 & s6 & s7 & s8 & \emph{something}  \\
\hline

\multirow[c]{3}{*}{jgifosjgs} & 
\multirow[c]{3}{*}{jgiosjgs} & gjiosfgjfsi 
& 5 & 10 & 52 & 3.27 & -086 & 0.03 & 3.9 & 2.01   \\ 
&& ngfiosjgofs & 37 & 3.1 & 73 & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5 & 2.58  \\
&& jgiofsjgfs & 2.6 & 65.4 & 57 & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10 & 9 & 82 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular*}
%}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rawfonts` and `epsfig` packages are 30-year-old compatibility layers for LaTeX 2.09 documents and they are not meant to be used in documents written after 1995.

Also `breqn` is an experimental package and may break several things. Loading `graphics` after `graphicx` is useless.

`hyperref` should be loaded last.

`\begin{table}[h!]` is not a good idea. And in one-column format, there is no reason for `table*`.

Resizing tables is a *bad* idea. I see no reason for definining columns that sum to more then the `\textwidth` and then scaling the table down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xr}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}

%\externaldocument{supp}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}


% \doublespacing

%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% correct bad hyphenation here


\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\footnotesize

\caption{Random Table}
\label{tab:main}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% leave TeX computing

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  c
  S[table-format=2.1] % s2
  S[table-format=2.1] % s3
  S[table-format=2.0] % s4
  S[table-format=1.2] % s5
  S[table-format=-1.2] % s6
  S[table-format=-1.2] % s7
  S[table-format=1.1] % s8
  S[table-format=2.2] % something
  @{}
}
\toprule

Dataset & ${n_{a}}$ & Method & {s2 (\%)} & {s3} & {s4 (\%)} &
{s5} & {s6} & {s7} & {s8} & {\emph{something}}  \\

\midrule

\multirow[c]{3}{*}{jgifosjgs}

& \multirow[c]{3}{*}{jgiosjgs} & gjiosfgjfsi & 5 & 10 & 52 & 3.27 & -0.86 & 0.03 & 3.9 & 2.01   \\ 
&& ngfiosjgofs & 37 & 3.1 & 73 & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5 & 2.58  \\
&& jgiofsjgfs & 2.6 & 65.4 & 57 & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10 & 9 & 82 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I doubt about the usefulness of `\multirow`: put those cells at the top of the group. I add an example of how I'd do it.

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  c
  S[table-format=2.1] % s2
  S[table-format=2.1] % s3
  S[table-format=2.0] % s4
  S[table-format=1.2] % s5
  S[table-format=-1.2] % s6
  S[table-format=-1.2] % s7
  S[table-format=1.1] % s8
  S[table-format=2.2] % something
  @{}
}
\toprule

Dataset & ${n_{a}}$ & Method & {s2 (\%)} & {s3} & {s4 (\%)} &
{s5} & {s6} & {s7} & {s8} & {\emph{something}}  \\

\midrule

jgifosjgs
& jgiosjgs & gjiosfgjfsi & 5 & 10 & 52 & 3.27 & -0.86 & 0.03 & 3.9 & 2.01   \\ 
&& ngfiosjgofs & 37 & 3.1 & 73 & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5 & 2.58  \\
&& jgiofsjgfs & 2.6 & 65.4 & 57 & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10 & 9 & 82 \\

\addlinespace

jgifosjgs
& jgiosjgs & gjiosfgjfsi & 5 & 10 & 52 & 3.27 & -0.86 & 0.03 & 3.9 & 2.01   \\ 
&& ngfiosjgofs & 37 & 3.1 & 73 & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5 & 2.58  \\
&& jgiofsjgfs & 2.6 & 65.4 & 57 & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10 & 9 & 82 \\

\addlinespace

jgifosjgs
& jgiosjgs & gjiosfgjfsi & 5 & 10 & 52 & 3.27 & -0.86 & 0.03 & 3.9 & 2.01   \\ 
&& ngfiosjgofs & 37 & 3.1 & 73 & 1.85 & 1.31 & -0.01 & 5 & 2.58  \\
&& jgiofsjgfs & 2.6 & 65.4 & 57 & 3.08 & 0.07 & 10 & 9 & 82 \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular*}
```

[image]